# C# MSChart Series Points not plotting

Tags: c#, winforms, series, mschart

I'm trying to make a "realtime" graph, everytime a method gets called - the chart should update with a new value but somehow the data is being written into the series array but not displayed in the chart.

```
foreach (Control c in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
{
    if (c is Panel)
    {
        Panel PanelControl = (Panel)c;
        foreach (Control c2 in PanelControl.Controls)
        {
            if (c2 is Chart)
            {
                Chart ChartControl = (Chart)c2;
                if (ChartControl.Name.Equals(Convert.ToString(host.HostIP)))
                    ChartControl.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, 10);                                     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do I have to add something more so that the chart is being updated with the data? What am I missing out? The error that I'm keep getting is "System.InvalidOperationExceptuion".

Thanks for help!

Comment: How is the initial datasource set?

Comment: what do you mean by initial datasource? I've only added chart.Series("Series1");

Comment: OK so you never gave it a datasource - which is normally how it works you can then add to the datasource

Comment: are you sure the points arent just overwriting the same spot as they all say 1,10

Comment: Indeed, @Bug is right: adding to the very same x-value __may or may not work__. This depends on whether the series is _indexed_. You can set `yourSeries.IsXValueIndexed = true;` to test, but more likely you want to create meaningful values for x- and y-values..

Comment: the problem is more likely that nothing is getting displayed to the chart expect the title even with meaningful values for x- and y. I tried setting Is.XValueIndexed to true but nothing really changed.

Comment: From my experience, looping through controls on a form doesn't always work.  Set a break point and make sure it's going into your `if (c2 is Chart)` statement.

Comment: @C.U: You can trust me on what at least some of the propblem are. But there may be others. It is up to you to do __all the debugging__!! We can't do that for you! So: Do you ever hit the `ChartControl.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, 10);` call?? Did you look at the `ChartControl.Series[0].Points` and check the point count and the values??

Comment: @TaW indeed I'm hitting the call. The count and values are fine aswell. Anyway the program isn't shutting down or anything but it's still throwing a "System.InvalidOperationException' occured in System.WIndows.Forms.dll in the debugger.

Comment: So I figured out that it is a cross-thread operation that's not valid. Now I should be able to solve this on my own.